# Cannot connect with a backup of a derby database using Netbeans or ij

Tags: database-connection, derby, netbeans-8

I back up regularly a derby database, that is on another server, simply by copying the location of the Derby database. So I have many backups depending on the date.

Now I am trying to connect to one of those backups from my computer, after installing Netbeans and Java 1.6 (becuase the app runs on this verion) and also installing derby.

The app connects with Java DB Network (clientDriver) and the connection URL is:

jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:Derby.DB

The error that I get is: Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to database using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: fail to start database with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@610455d6, see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE:X0Y32

- The error message associated with SQLSTATE:X0Y32 is of the form  '' already exists in  ''

Ive investigated a lot and tried many options with no solution.

Please help!
Thank you

Ive already tried to connect from ij and get the exact same error.

Ive tried to connect from the server and re-direct to the back database and get the exact same error.

Also, when I try to connect through the Embedded Driver, I get this error:

ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:C:/database';

> ---------------------------------------------------------------- Tue Apr 02 08:39:43 COT 2019:  Iniciando instancia
>   f81e0010-0169-dae4-8f03-00000e572d50 de Derby, versi¾n The Apache
>   Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.12.1.1 - (1704137): in the
>   database directory using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@66d3c617
>   Loaded from
>   file:/C:/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derby.jar
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation java.runtime.version=1.8.0_201-b09
>   user.dir=C:\ os.name=Windows 10 os.arch=amd64 os.version=10.0
>   derby.system.home=null Cargador de clases de base de datos iniciado -
>   derby.database.classpath=''
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------- Tue Apr 02 08:39:43 COT 2019: Cerrando la instancia
>   f81e0010-0169-dae4-8f03-00000e572d50 en el directorio de base de datos
>   C:\database con cargador de clases
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@66d3c617 Tue Apr 02 08:39:43 COT 2019
>   Thread[main,5,main] Cleanup action starting java.sql.SQLException:
>   Cannot establish a connection to database using
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@66d3c617, consulte la excepci¾n
>   siguiente para obtener mßs informaci¾n.
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.dynamicConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.ConnectStatement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.ijStatement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.utilMain.runScriptGuts(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.utilMain.go(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.go(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.mainCore(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.main(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.tools.ij.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Cannot establish a connection to database using
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@66d3c617, consulte la excepci¾n
>   siguiente para obtener mßs informaci¾n.
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown
>   Source)
>           ... 23 more Caused by: ERROR X0Y32: Statement 'getUDTs' already exists in Schema 'SYS'.
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.addSPSDescriptor(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.createSPSSet(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.createSystemSps(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.updateMetadataSPSes(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DD_Version.handleMinorRevisionChange(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DD_Version.upgradeIfNeeded(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.loadDictionaryTables(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           ... 20 more
>   ============= begin nested exception, level (1) =========== java.sql.SQLException: Statement 'getUDTs' already exists in Schema
>   'SYS'.
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.dynamicConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.ConnectStatement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.ijStatement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.utilMain.runScriptGuts(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.utilMain.go(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.go(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.mainCore(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.main(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.tools.ij.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: ERROR X0Y32: Statement 'getUDTs' already exists in Schema 'SYS'.
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.addSPSDescriptor(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.createSPSSet(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.createSystemSps(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.updateMetadataSPSes(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DD_Version.handleMinorRevisionChange(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DD_Version.upgradeIfNeeded(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.loadDictionaryTables(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           ... 20 more
>   ============= end nested exception, level (1) ===========
>   ============= begin nested exception, level (2) =========== ERROR X0Y32: Statement 'getUDTs' already exists in Schema 'SYS'.
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.addSPSDescriptor(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.createSPSSet(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.createSystemSps(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.updateMetadataSPSes(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DD_Version.handleMinorRevisionChange(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DD_Version.upgradeIfNeeded(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.loadDictionaryTables(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.dynamicConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.ConnectStatement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.ij.ijStatement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.utilMain.runScriptGuts(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.utilMain.go(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.go(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.mainCore(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.tools.ij.Main.main(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.tools.ij.main(Unknown Source)
>   ============= end nested exception, level (2) =========== Cleanup action completed ERROR XJ040: Cannot establish a connection to
>   database using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@66d3c617, consulte la
>   excepcion siguiente para obtener mas informacion. ERROR X0Y32:
>   Statement 'getUDTs' already exists in Schema 'SYS'.

Comment: My guess is that you have forgotten to start the Derby Network Server, but that's just a guess. When it says "see the next exception for details", do this: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain  Also, look for a 'derby.log' that is getting created by your Derby Network Server and see what it says.

Comment: [1] [The error message](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefexcept71493.html) associated with `SQLSTATE:X0Y32` is of the form **<value> '<value>' already exists in <value> '<value>'** but it is not shown in your question. Could you update your question to include it? [2] What is "ij"?

Comment: Ok, I'll add it

Comment: And also I've started the Derby Network Server in many ways, through Netbeans and also through startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0 in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Im posting this because finally I could recover the corrupted table and for somenone that would find this helpful.

What I did after replacing these files: c230.dat, c241.dat and c251.dat

I investigated how to recover corrupted tables and found this great page:

https://givemethechills.com/recovering-a-corrupted-embedded-apache-derby-database-after-an-error-xj040-or-if-you-get-an-error-xsdg2/

That basically gave these steps:

1. Download the latest derby bin.
2. Add **DerbyRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** to the **ij** classpath
3. Run **dataFileVTI.sql** (remember to change the route to the database in the connect string)
4. Enter **ij** and connect to the database using `upgrade=true`
5. Use `call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_REGISTER_TOOL('customTool',true,'RawDBReader', 'CONTROL','RAW_','c:db','','APP',null);` -> change the db route, password, bootpassword and schema
6. Check with `select * from raw_app.table1;`

I only got the 3rd step and then decided to restore the database with this command in **ij**:

`jdbc:derby:sample;restoreFrom=c:\Derby.DB`

and this worked. After this I could access the table that I needed, with all the records.

So probably only running this command in **ij** worked after replacing the files, but I'm posting everything I did just in case.

Thanks to all that helped!
Karina S.

Answer (score 0):

[This is not really a solution, but is too long to post as a comment.]

Someone else had the same problem as you (`ERROR X0Y32: Statement 'getUDTs' already exists...`). See Bug Report DERBY-5371: [Database fails to boot, complaining that the getProcedureColumns() system procedure already exists](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5371)

The final comment in the thread states:

> I had a customer who was also hit by this problem on an old database,
>   with the same error that Andreas reported.
>
> `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Statement 'getUDTs' already exists
>   in Schema 'SYS'.`
>
> Running the command:
>
> `values syscs_util.syscs_get_database_property( 'DataDictionaryVersion'
>   )`
>
> returned 10.5.
>
> I used the same trick of loading fresh c230.dat, c241.dat and c251.dat files in order to get the database to boot.

I'm not sure what exactly has to be done to load *"fresh c230.dat, c241.dat and c251.dat files in order to get the database to boot"*, but if that makes sense to you it might be worth trying.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot! It pointed me in the right direction, what happened is that I replaced those files from a new database and it worked, I could connect with the database. I guess it has to do with some corrupted files.

Comment: Now the thing is that I wanted the records from one table and that table is the corrupt one, gonna keep on trying to recover those, thank you!

Comment: @KarinaS Great. If you come up with a solution please post an answer to your own question since that will be helpful for the community.